# Java Var-arg Overloading

Tags: java

Недавно столкнулся с таким вот примером :

```
 static void show(int ... arg) {
    System.out.println("int");
}

static void show(Integer ... arg) {
    System.out.println("Integer");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    show(1,2);
}
```

В результате компиляции выкидывает Error : 
The method show(int[]) is ambiguous

хотя :

```
static void show(int arg) {
    System.out.println("int");
}

static void show(Integer arg) {
    System.out.println("Integer");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    show(1); // int
}
```

**var-arg** внутри себя создает массив и ложит туда наши аргументы которые пришли в метод , получается что компилятор в момент компиляции обнаруживает что эти два метода идентичны , но почему ?? один метод принимает примитивы , другой объекты . Могу только предположить что там идет какае-то магия с автобоксингом , так как компилятор может сделать автобоксинг для примитива то получается что он при создании  массива внутри может легко обернуть примитив в обьект и создать массив Integer[].

---

Кто может дать ответ почему так ?

Answer (score 4):

Это баг. См. багрепорты:

- [6886431 : Handling of "most specific" varargs method inconsistent with JLS](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6886431)
- [6199075 : Unambiguous varargs method calls flagged as ambiguous](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6886431).